# How to prevent emacs from hard-wrapping lines

Tags: shell, unix, emacs

I am working on emacs from UNIX shell, and emacs is always hard-wrapping lines instead of soft-wrapping. How can I change that behavior?

Comment: -1 for terseness and lack of detail.

Comment: What major mode are you using (e.g. `text-mode`)? Are you using any minor modes, like `auto-fill-mode`?

Comment: @event_jr "Emacs" and "hard-wrapping" give all the information. What detail do you think is needed? If you think the description lacks something, please point it out so I can make improvement. Otherwise, -1 your comment for terseness and lack of detail. Thanks.

Comment: @Lindydancer Since I am a new Emacs user, I know nothing about the modes (anyway, I read the tutorial.) I just used `emacs sometextfile.txt` to launch it in shell.

Comment: @event_jr I don't think anything is wrong with lack of detail/terseness; it is actually preferred as long as people understand the question?

Comment: @Dualinity Well, I guess event_jr's expectation on newbies is just too high. Since I'm new to emacs I barely know anything about it, so I can't go into details. After all, if I know the details, why do I come here and ask such a naive question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
M-x auto-fill-mode RET
```